# How to use order by in date using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i am using mySql database.But when i sort date it was not sort.

```
SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER By `nextDate` ASC
```

this is my query i want all data with sort date in ascending order from client table and `nextDate` field type is varchar. so please how can i sort date in ascending order.and i want date formate like 24/12/2016(d/m/Y).

when i use this query it will sort only first day not a month like this

```
01/08/2016
07/10/2016
21/08/2016
```

but i want sort like this

```
01/08/2016
07/08/2016
21/10/2016
25/12/2016
```

so please help me how can i do.in advance thax,

Comment: You have to use DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data type. rather then you can not do sorting using date

Comment: ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(table_date, '%D%M %Y') ASC ;

Comment: Store dates using a suitable date data type.

Comment: try my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you are not storing the date as a *date*. Instead you are storing it as a string. You should use the built-in MySQL data types -- that is what they are there for. If you *have to* store a date as a string, then always use `YYYY-MM-DD` format. It sorts correctly.

You can fix this with `str_to_date()`:

```
ORDER By str_to_date(`nextDate`, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

use mysql `STR_TO_DATE`

You can use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your strings to MySQL date values and ORDER BY the result:

```
SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`nextDate`, '%d/%m/%Y') ASC ;
```

---

**Note:**

***Dates should be stored in a date datatype.***

If you want to convert all your date strings to valid dates (`yyyy-mm-dd`) then follow the steps below:

**Steps in a nutshell:**

First update all the current date strings into valid date format:

```
UPDATE `client` 
SET `nextDate` = STR_TO_DATE(`nextDate`, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Now change the datatype of `nextDate` column to `date`:

```
ALTER TABLE client MODIFY nextDate DATE;
```

Comment: your date format is valid for this kind of dates: `29th/August/2016`

Comment: You can add suggestion to convert the datatype of that column to `date` type. Would you mind if I edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
"select  * from `client` ORDER BY nextDate ASC";
```

please use TIMESTAMP in databse entry the nextDate data type.

Answer (score 0):

[STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

> This is the inverse of the DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a string
>   str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value
>   if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or
>   TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts. If the
>   date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal,
>   STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning.
>   For example

```
 mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/31/2004', '%m/%d/%Y');
            -> '2004-04-31'
```

here is your query

```
SELECT  * FROM `client` ORDER By  STR_TO_DATE(`nextDate`,'%m/%d/%Y') ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

1) Change data type for `nextDate` column to date. Use below query

```
ALTER TABLE `client` CHANGE `nextDate` `date` nextDate NOT NULL;
```

Then use your select query as you stated

```
SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER By `nextDate` ASC
```

2) If you do not want to alter the table schema, then

```
SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(nextDate, '%Y-%M-%D') ASC
```

Comment: Before changing the datatype you need to update the date strings in `yyyy-mm-dd` format otherwise all data will be lost and you will see dates look like `0000-00-00`. Check @jothi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER BY DATE(`nextDate`) ASC
```

it is useful for your date in ascending order, when you store your date as a date

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.